# Simple "realtime" search using listview and streamreader

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to make a simple realtime search using a streamreader to read from a txt file and search and display the results in a listview, problem is I can only search for 1 letter, so searching for "1" will show me results for everything starting with 1, example search 1 results in "123", but searching for "12" or "123" wont show the same result. Easier explained with this code I've tried.

Edit, text-file I'm reading from has this structure:
123;asd;asd;asd;asd;asd;asd <- example of a row

```
    public static string[] testtt(string sökord)
    {
        StreamReader asd = new StreamReader("film.txt");
        string temp;
        string[] xd;

        while (asd.Peek() >= 0) // if I can read another row (I.E next row isnt empty)
        {
            temp = asd.ReadLine();
            xd = temp.Split(';');

            for (int i = 0; i < xd.Length; i++)
            {
                // this should check if my searchword is equal to any member of "xd"
                // but this is where the problem occurs when the input is more than 1
                // character, will post error message from debugger below this code.
                if (xd[i].Substring(0, sökord.Length).ToLower() == sökord.ToLower())
                    return xd;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(testtt(textBox1.Text)[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[1]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[2]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[3]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[4]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[5]);
            item.SubItems.Add(testtt(textBox1.Text)[6]);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);

            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                listView1.Items.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

ex

```
{"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.\r\nParameter name: length"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
```

Comment: An example of your input data and the "desired" output might be more helpfull. And why do you call your "search function" in the TextChanged event several times with the same parameter?

Comment: Edited the question with how the text-file is structured.
Example of input: searching for "1" will give me an array with the values from the textfile separated by semi-colons IF "1" is the first letter in any of the separated words on a row in the file. Searching for "12" wont give me any result even if the first 2 characters are "12" and thats my problem. And I call it with same parameter but different index since its an array the method returns.

Comment: And you want a "match" if any of the "elements" of one inputline STARTSWITH (hint hint!) your searchword?

Comment: Yep, that is correct. Got it working by simply checking the length of the input as suggested below so I'm all good now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple. This error will always appear when the line you have read form the stream reader, and you split and store the value in xd. Say the length of xd is n. And the sokord string you entered has say m length. Now when you write:
`(xd[i].Substring(0, sökord.Length)`
whenever the length of xd that is n is less than m, the Substring function would be trying to make a substring of m letters from only n letters. And hence it gives the error you mentioned.

In any case just a simple check should do ok:

```
    String sString = null;
    if(xd[i].length>=sokord.length){
        sString = xd[i].SubString(0,sokord.length).toLower();
        if(sString.equals(sokord.toLower()))
            return xd;
    }
```

Digvijay

PS: To be honest I have written the answer from what best I could understand of what is trying to be done, so the code might be a little offtrack in one scenario. But in any case the error i have described above is 100% correct. So it would be best if you just look into that and follow the track. =)

Comment: Thanks alot, I thought that error would be cought and that the loop would just continue on anyways.. added if(xd[i].length>=sokord.length) and worked perfectly as intended! Great answer, glad you understood what I meant despite a rather weird description... :)

Answer (score 0):

Still dont know if I understood the question correctly, but wouldnt this be much easier to read and understand?

```
    private String[] FindSome(String searchword)
    { 
        foreach (String s in System.IO.File.ReadLines("myfile.txt"))
        {
            String[] tmp = s.Split('c');
            foreach (String t in tmp)
            {
                if (t.StartsWith(searchword,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return tmp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```